# why is my page redirect code using express.js not working?

Tags: node.js, express, backend

I am kinda new to backend. I am making a simple products page. I am trying to make a redirect command using `res.redirect` after the submit button is clicked. However after clicking on it, the page keeps loading forever and nothing happens.

[this is the image of current demo page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJJPb.png)

here is menu.ejs```

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<div>
  Choose what you want to have-
</div>
<form action="/CheckOut" method="post">
  <div class="lays">lays</div>
  <input type="number" value="0" id="input" name="input" />
  <button id="minus">−</button>
  <button id="plus">+</button>
  <input type="submit" id="placeorder"></input>
</form>



<script>
  const placeorder = document.getElementById("checkout");
  const minusButton = document.getElementById('minus');
  const plusButton = document.getElementById('plus');
  const inputField = document.getElementById('input');

  minusButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const currentValue = Number(inputField.value) || 0;
    if (inputField.value > 0) {
      inputField.value = currentValue - 1;
    }
  });


  plusButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const currentValue = Number(inputField.value) || 0;
    inputField.value = currentValue + 1;
  });
  placeorder.addEventListener('click', event => {
    event.preventDefault();

  })
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Below is my backend script.js

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const { name } = require("ejs")

const order = []
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}))

app.post("/CheckOut", async(req, res) => {
    try {
      order.push({
      amount: req.body.input
      }) 
        console.log(order)
    } catch (e){
      res.redirect("/orderpage")
  console.log("e");    
    }
})
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("menu.ejs")})
  app.get("/orderPage", (req, res) => {
    res.render("orderPage.ejs")})

app.listen(8000)
```

Below is image of file structure.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3t6m.png)

I cant find anything to try. I tried renaming files and also changing dirs but doesnt help. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your pages aren't in the root directory.

Maybe something like:-

```
var htmlPath = path.join(__dirname, '/views/');
app.use(express.static(htmlPath));
```

would get them from the views directory.

Comment: Its still not working. The page keeps loading and never ends.